# How to order django queryset using the Choices displayed label?

Tags: django, django-models

Is it possible to order the query set by choices displayed label? If not, can you please advise on how to achieve this? Or is there a way to create a custom ordering?

Thanks in advance!

**Choices**

```
C_TYPES = Choices(
    ('ac_sm', 'ac_sm', _('Ta-Class - Small')),
    ('ac_md', 'ac_md', _('Ta-Class - Medium')),
    ('ac_lg', 'ac_lg', _('Ta-Class - Large')),
)
```

**Model**

```
class FactoryLeadType():

    c_type = models.CharField(
        _('Chiller Type'),
        choices=C_TYPES ,
        default=C_TYPES .ac_sm,
        max_length=50,
    )


class Meta:
    ordering = ( `get_c_type_display()` )
```

Comment: You can't do this in a queryset (unless with a large case-when branch, but that will usually perform worse), if you really want to do this, you will need to sort the queryset at Python level (for example with `sorted(my_qs, key=lambda x: x.get_c_type_display())`.

Comment: Choices is a front end user choice, so you can't use it to specify a classes default ordering on something that is a multi user system, what happens when people make different selections?